# How do devDependencies work when you yarn add <package>?

Tags: npm, dependencies, yarnpkg

If you have a project that depends on packageA and you `yarn add packageA` but packageA has a devDependency on packageB to build, shouldn't that cause packageA to not work for you? Since packageA won't be able to build unless its devDependencies are installed too?

I guess my main question is if a pacakge has a devDependency on a built tool like babel, how does it get built and work when it gets `yarn add`ed by a project? Shouldn't build tools like webpack be a normal dependency?

Answer (score 0):

No, they shouldn't, because the package that is `yarn add`ed is already built in an environment where the devDependencies are available. For example, when a package needs babel or webpack to build, then during the publishing a built bundle is created in a CI/CD pipeline that is valid es5 code and that is what you pull from npm. No build required after that.

Answer (score -3):

**GOOD MORNING :)**

If you are having dependency problems on your dependencies of package.json, it is very simple to solve =]
What happens is that the dependency modules that the modules of your project need (dependencies) must be installed in the global npm as a package node (module), that is:

```
npm install -g youPackageName
```

If you have already installed a module in other projects or in the current project and want to turn it into a global package, you can use the command:

```
npm link youPackageName
```